# Populate multiple columns into rows while retaining information in some columns (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to look for VBA codes which is able to transform my current table (from A1) into the expected format (A7) as shown in the table below.

[Current Vs Expected]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUQEU.png

I tried doing this but it does not populate over column 1 to 3 to the rows below as well.

```
Sub ConvertTable()
'Update 20150512
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cRng As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim xOutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set cRng = Application.InputBox("Select your Column labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set rRng = Application.InputBox("Select Your Row Labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select your data", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set outRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set xWs = Rng.Worksheet
k = 1
xColumns = rRng.Column
xRow = cRng.Row
For i = Rng.Rows(1).Row To Rng.Rows(1).Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
    For j = Rng.Columns(1).Column To Rng.Columns(1).Column +     Rng.Columns.Count - 1
    outRng.Cells(k, 1) = xWs.Cells(i, xColumns)
    outRng.Cells(k, 2) = xWs.Cells(xRow, j)
    outRng.Cells(k, 3) = xWs.Cells(i, j)
    k = k + 1
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help please!

Comment: Maybe it would help showing, what (result in Excel) your code generates so far to better understand your code. Also replace the input Boxes by constants for easier replication. A sample table for copying and pasting into excel would help reducing the work for people trying to help(also increasing the chance that you get an answer). Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: Hi, the input boxes were there because I need it to be flexible on the amount of columns. I'm new to stackoverflow so I haven't figure out how to copy a table into the post to allow for easier copying. Do let me know so that I can also help to make it easier for people to replicate it :) I'm using Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertTable()
    'Update 20150512
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Range, rRng As Range, rng As Range, outRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim xTitleId As String, YN As Variant

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    
    ' input
    Set cRng = Application.InputBox("Select your Column labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set rRng = Application.InputBox("Select Your Row Labels", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select your data", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set outRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set xWs = rng.Worksheet

    ' output
    n = cRng.Columns.Count ' no of columns
    outRng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, n).Value2 = cRng.Value2
    outRng.Offset(0, n + 1) = "Answer" ' add on end
    r = 1
    For i = 1 To rRng.Columns.Count
    
        For j = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            YN = rng.Cells(j, n + i).Value2 ' Yes/No
            
            If IsError(YN) Then
                ' skip if error
            ElseIf YN <> "" And YN <> 0 Then
                ' skip if 0 or blank
                outRng.Offset(r, 0) = rRng.Cells(1, i)
                For k = 1 To n
                    If Not IsError(rng.Cells(j, k)) Then
                        outRng.Offset(r, k).Value2 = rng.Cells(j, k).Value2
                    End If
                Next
                outRng.Offset(r, n + 1).Value2 = YN
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

update - exclude rows with #N/A in Answer column

update2 - exclude blanks and 0

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to exclude an error cell because it's blank?

Comment: @user164 Do you mean exclude a cell in the data range `rng` with `#N/A` in it ?

Comment: not for all rng, just for the Answer column (the one with "Yes" and "No" value in the example)

Comment: I see that you have added in the If condition for error. If I want to skip other values such as blank (cell is empty) or cell = 0, do I just substitute the part where If Not IsError(YN) with YN = "" and YN = 0?

Comment: If Not (YN = "") Or (YN = 0) Then
                outRng.Offset(r, 0) = rRng.Cells(1, i)
                For k = 1 To n
                    If Not (rng.Cells(j, k) = "") Or (rng.Cells(j, k) = 0) Then
                        outRng.Offset(r, k).Value2 = rng.Cells(j, k).Value2
                    End If
                Next
                outRng.Offset(r, n + 1).Value2 = YN
                r = r + 1
            End If

Comment: @user16405 If you want only Yes/No then easiest is to use `If YN="Yes" or YN="No" Then` in place of `If Not IsError(YN) Then`

Comment: The answer column may be a value or blank as well depending on column A to D, so I'm trying to extend it to not include blank or 0. But when I tried the edited version If Not (YN = "") Or (YN = 0) its not working.

Comment: Hi, the blank cells and cells with 0 for the "Answer" field are still being populated.